# Construct a space with given fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am trying to find out how to construct a space with the following fundamental group:
$ \pi_{1}(X)= \langle a,b, c \mid b^{2}ac, c^{-1}a^{2} \rangle$

What is the main strategy for solving this kind of exercises? Do i have to try to modify the relations so that i can get a space with known relations like the torus, Klein bottle and projective plane?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The first thing to note is that $c^{-1}a^2=e \implies a^2=c$, and so the presentation you have can be simplified to only have two generators $a, b$ and the relation $b^2a^3=e$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! So, the space is kind of Klein bottle with one extra edge $a$ in the polygonal presentation?

Comment: Are you aware of fundamental groups of knot complements, especially torus knots? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774198/fundamental-group-of-mathbbr3-minus-trefoil-knot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a CW-complex: start with a point $p$, attach 1-cells $a$ and $b$ with their boundaries identified with $p$, and then attach a 2-cell with boundary $b^2a^3$. In general this process works for constructing a space with a fundamental group given by generators and relations.

If you're curious about constructing spaces with given homotopy groups more generally, here is a note on that topic: http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~xiyin/Site/Notes_files/AT.pdf