# Fundamental group of S_3 without curve

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Define $S^3$ as 
$$
S^3 = \left\lbrace (z_1, z_2) \mid |z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 2  \right\rbrace
$$
and curve $C$ as
$$
C(t) = (e^{imt}, e^{int}) 
$$
for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that gcd(m,n) = 1. 
The task is to find $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus  C).$ I know that I should use Seifert–van Kampen theorem here, but I don't know what to start with. May somebody suggest something?

Comment: As you've written it $C(t)\notin S^3$. It looks like a torus knot to me.

Comment: Thanks for correction. It is a torus knot actually. Look for easiest method. The one I found in Hatcher(ex. 1.24) is hard for me to understand.

Comment: Did you look here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774198/fundamental-group-of-mathbbr3-minus-trefoil-knot?