# Why a torus minus a trefoil is a annulus?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to visulize a torus minus a trefoil is an annulus. How to deformation retract $S^1\times S^1\setminus T $ where $T$ is trefoil? If we thicken torus, will $S^1\times S^1\setminus T $ deformation retract to $S^1\times S^1\setminus A $ where $A$ is annulus?

Comment: It is perhaps easier to think of the torus as a square with edges identified. The trefoil is just a few lines with slope $3/2$ (which is really just one line when you wrap up the square).

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1774198

Comment: @Tipping Octopus So, actually every torus knot can be represented by some line on square right?

Comment: Every simple homotopically nontrivial loop on $T^2$ is isotopic to a geodesic loop, i.e. the projection of a straight line in the Euclidean plane.